# Каким образом проверить строку на значение нуль

Tags: javascript, html, css

Функция выводит последний элемент, но как провести правильную проверку на ноль я не знаю, точнее как я сделал она не работает. В чем проблема?

```
function div(input) 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("t");
    var lastElement = (input.value.length-1);
    alert(input.value.charAt(lastElement));//заглушка для проверки

    if (input.value.charAt(lastElement) == 0)
    { 
        alert(" / to Zero");
    }
}
```

Comment: что в input.value может быть?

Comment: По-моему уже третий вопрос на ту же тему, может лучше поправить предыдущие вопросы?

Answer (score 0):

При проектировании калькулятора нужно помнить о следующем математическом правиле:
Число над которым проводится манипуляция называется - **оперируемое**;
Вид операции называется - **оператор**, например **"+"** или **"-"**;
Число на которое манипулируют называют - **операнд**;
Так вот, необходимо проверять оператор и если он "/", проверять операнд на ноль.
  Например:

```js
var operate = prompt('число','');
 var operator = prompt('операция "+", "-","*","/" ','');
 var operand = prompt('число','');
 var result;
 switch (operator) {
     case "+": {
         result = +operate + +operand;
         document.write('Резултат' + result);
     }
     break;
     case "-": {
         result = +operate - +operand;
         document.write('Резултат' + result);
     }
     break;
     case "*": {
         result = +operate * +operand;
         document.write('Резултат' + result);
     }
     break;
     case "/": {
         if (operand == 0){
             document.write('На ноль делить нельзя');
         }
         else{
         result = +operate /  +operand;
         document.write('Резултат' + result);
        }
     }
     break;
 }
```